# Xstream generated json response for List<Object>

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, xstream

I am using Xstream to generate JSON for my application.I want to use JSON for ajax support. When i try

```
     xstream.alias(classAlias, jsonModel.getClass()); //Note classAlias="records"
responseStream.println(xstream.toXML(jsonModel));
```

where jsonModel is actually a List of  entity objects.Entity class name is **Person** which is in "**beans**" package so full qualified name would be **beans.Person**. OK
Person class has properties like id,name,age etc.

Generated JSON is

```
   {"records":[{"beans.Person":[{"id":21,"name":"Name21","username":"Username21","password":"password21","age":41,"sex":true},{"id":22,"name":"Name22","username":"Username22","password":"password22","age":42,"sex":true},{"id":23,"name":"Name23","username":"Username23","password":"password23","age":43,"sex":true},{"id":24,"name":"Name24","username":"Username24","password":"password24","age":44,"sex":true},{"id":25,"name":"Name25","username":"Username25","password":"password25","age":45,"sex":true},{"id":26,"name":"Name26","username":"Username26","password":"password26","age":46,"sex":true},{"id":27,"name":"Name27","username":"Username27","password":"password27","age":47,"sex":true},{"id":28,"name":"Name28","username":"Username28","password":"password28","age":48,"sex":true},{"id":29,"name":"Name29","username":"Username29","password":"password29","age":49,"sex":true},{"id":30,"name":"Name30","username":"Username30","password":"password30","age":50,"sex":true}]}]}
```

I used $.getJSON of jquery to get this response on button click event. I checked the status which is "**success**" every time so this is working well.Problem occurs when i try to access first records i.e. person's information like id,username etc.

I write statements in Javascript as

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("input").click(function(){
                $.getJSON("http://mylocalhost:8080/Paging/paging/records?page=3",function(data,status){

                    alert(status);
                    alert(data.records[0].beans.Person[0].id);
                });
            });
        });

    </script>
```

First alert works but second doesn't.

Then javascript stops working as it does whenever encounters an error.What i can guess is that in records array Person object is followed by package name.This could be the reason because browser may look for beans object in records array which is not there because beans.Person is a single, atomic name in this case as shown in above. But not sure?

If this is actually problem then how can i stop/control XStream to name an object's name  as  just **classname**(person) instead of **package.classname**(beans.person) as it is being named by default.

or If everything is OK in produced JSON object then why can't i see the expected result? Why simple second alert statement is not working.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer I was to use

```
 alert(data.records[0]["beans.Person"][0].id);
```

instead of

```
 alert(data.records[0].beans.Person[0].id);
```

A useful link

http://www.javascripttoolbox.com/bestpractices/#squarebracket